# Joins in Linq 2 SQL using IDataContext

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've an interface for my dbContext class as follows

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
  {
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class ;
    .... Other methods
  }
```

and my implementation of this is like this

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class
    {
      return Set<T>();
    }
```

Now when I do query like this

```
     var menus = (from s in _dbContext.Query<SiteMenu>()
               from r in _dbContext.Query<RoleMenu>()
               where r.Role.Name == rolename
               select s).ToList();
```

I got the following error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[G.Domain.Models.Models.RoleMenu] Query[RoleMenu] ()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I've to make explicit join to make this work, Can you explain this ?

Comment: The Query<RoleMenu> is the same IQueryable<T>

Comment: Can't reproduce this (assuming that `_dbContext` is a subclass of `DbContext`).

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have a perfect looking LINQ query like this:

```
var menus = (from s in _dbContext.Query<SiteMenu>()
               from r in _dbContext.Query<RoleMenu>()
               where r.Role.Name == rolename
               select s).ToList();
```

If the Query method calls some custom method inside of it, it will be embedded into the logic trying to convert this LINQ query into SQL, and attempt to convert any method calls into an appropriate SQL method.  There is limited method support in LINQ, and as such it finds the method "QueryRoleMenu" that it can't convert to SQL, and throws this exception.

Comment: Actually there is nothing inside the Query<T> function beside the one I supplied in the questions, but this still not clear to me

Comment: Ok then it may be literally trying to translate the query method you are calling in LINQ...  The error message is exactly referring to what I said is normally the issue...